# Does the epilogue scene from Rebels occur before or after Season 2 of The Mandalorian

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, the-mandalorian, chronological-order, ahsoka-tano

Marked spoilers for Rebels S4 and The Mandalorian S2.

The final scene of Star Wars Rebels occurs after the events of the original trilogy with

> Sabine recounting the exploits of the surviving Spectres from the liberation of Lothal to the Battle of Endor, and then Ahsoka arriving with the suggestion the two are to go off in search of Ezra, who was last seen being dragged off to an unknown destination by the purrgil along with Thrawn in the Rebels finale.

Then in Season Two of the The Mandalorian, Chapter 13: The Jedi, we have:

> Ahsoka Tano hunting for Grand Admiral Thrawn.

What is the chronological order of these two events?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Mandalorian* episode likely comes later. The epilogue is seemingly set shortly after the defeat of the Empire in *Return of the Jedi*, which would put it around 5 ABY (ROTJ ending at 4 ABY). [*The Mandalorian* was stated as starting five years after *Return of the Jedi*](https://www.starwars.com/news/swcc-2019-9-things-we-learned-from-the-mandalorian-panel), which would mean about a four year gap.

Of course, this is not certain, and [Dave Filoni has indicated that it's possible](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2020/11/rosario-dawson-dave-filoni-mandalorian-ahsoka-tano-grogu) that the epilogue didn't start shortly after the Battle of Endor.

> “Right. But no, it’s an interesting one… That’s not necessarily chronological. I think the thing that people will most not understand is they want to go in a linear fashion, but as I learned as a kid, nothing in Star Wars really works in a linear fashion. You do [Episodes] Four, Five and Six and then One, Two, and Three. So in the vein of that history, when you look at the epilogue of Rebels you don’t really know how much time has passed. So, it’s *possible* that the story I’m telling in *The Mandalorian* actually takes place prior to that. Possible. I’m saying it’s possible.”

Comment: I don't think that timing has been firmly established.  Filoni himself said "it is possible the Epilogue happened after".  Source: https://starwarsthoughts.com/2020/12/03/dave-filoni-its-possible-that-rebels-epilogue-happens-after-the-mandalorian/

Comment: {nods} It's ambiguous. Even Jacen doesn't really help clarify since he looks like he could be anywhere between 5-10, which could place the immediately preceding scene before or after *The Mandalorian*.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this will be the accepted answer, but I'll give it 24 hours in case someone can find a more recent article where Filoni contradicts that.